# Angular2 how to override attributes via ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some code that looks like

```html
  <ng-container>
    <ng-content select="[content-body]"></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
```

I need to override an attribute on the top div in the ng-content.  For example, if I need to add the html element attribute `tabindex = "-1"` via the container Component.

```html
<div content-body>
  Hello World
</div>
```

Needs to become

```html
<html>
  <div tabindex="-1">
    Hello World
  </div>
</html>
```

I don't want to have to update every `<div content-body>` in the codebase.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't CSS be a better place to put width formatting? Or do you have a need for other types of attributes?

Comment: Other type of attributes.  tabIndex in particular.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I can think to assign attributes to projected content.

Approach 1: (Preferred IMO) Use directive for content selection, and put your business logic in that directive to assign attribute values to host. For example:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appProductItemsContentBody]'
})
export class ProductItemsContentBodyDirective {

  @HostBinding('style.width') width = '200px';
  @HostBinding('style.height') height = '200px';
  @HostBinding('style.background-color') bgColor = 'yellow';
}
```

And use this directive to project your content as follows:

```
  <ng-container>
    <ng-content select="[appProductItemsContentBody]"></ng-content>
  </ng-container>
```

Put your content in your component as follow:

```
<app-product-items>
  <div appProductItemsContentBody>
    Hello World
  </div>

  <div appProductItemsContentBody *ngIf="showItem2">
    Item 2
  </div>
</app-product-items>
```

If you have more complexities and need to assign attributes based on some business logic in host component, then you can inject new service using dependency injection that will provide communication between directive and host component.

Approach 2:
Declare directive and use "@ContentChildren" or "@ContentChild" to find projected content and assign attributes directly.

You can find out multiple content body items as follows:
      @ContentChildren(ProductItemsContentBodyDirective, { read: ElementRef }) contentBodyItems: QueryList;

Then, assign attributes using 'setStyle' and other methods on ElementRef.

Hope this helps.

See example at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngcontent-attribute-assign

Comment: It's important to note with these approaches that the Directive needs to be imported into both of the components that have `appProductItemsContentBody` in their templates.  Accordingly, this doesn't exactly do what I wanted as it requires a change in code in the places where the component is used.
This can be seen in the example provided in this answer.